# Certificate with Extended Key Usage only works in Firefox

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, x509

I tried to generate a self-sign certificate to my server for multiple domains. I used openssl basing in v3_req extension.
I used this command line to generate certificate with multiple domain and extended key usage:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in san_domain_com.csr -signkey san_domain_com.key -out san_domain_com.crt -extensions v3_req -extensions mysection -extfile openssl.cnf
```

It's result that my certificate contains the multiple domain but not the extended Key Usage for serverauth and the clientauth also my website is only accessible from Firefox.
Does someone have idea about this? 
Thank you

My `openssl.conf` file was structured like this :

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        = 
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca' and 'req'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

streetAddress = 2.5.4.9
postalCode = 2.5.4.17
POBox = 2.5.4.18

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = ./demoCA      # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extentions to add to the cert

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha1          # which md to use
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
default_md      = sha1
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
#attributes     = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options. 
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString.
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings.
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: current versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings
# so use this option with caution!
string_mask = nombstr

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Nom du pays (code ISO a 2 lettres)
countryName_default     = FR
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = Nom du departement
stateOrProvinceName_default = Alpes Maritimes
stateOrProvinceName_max         = 64

localityName            = Nom de la ville
localityName_default        = Nice
localityName_max                = 64

organizationName        = Raison Sociale (nom officiel de l organisation)
organizationName_default    = Michel Durand SA
organizationName_max            = 64

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Nom commercial, service, ou texte libre (optionnel)
organizationalUnitName_default  = Fourni par TBS internet
organizationalUnitName_max      = 64

commonName          = Adresse du site a securiser (FQDN de votre site)
commonName_default      = www.monsitessl.fr
commonName_max          = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = abc.bce.com
DNS.2 = abc.bced.com
DNS.3 = abc.bced.com

[ mysection ]
keyUsage         = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming at all.

Comment: Please show us the certificate. Use `openssl x509 -in <certificate file> -inform PEM -text -noout`. There could be other problems beside Extended Key Usage. And you can delete OpenSSL's sample CONF file. Its not needed and just takes up space (especially the irrelevant sections).

Answer (score 8):

> Does someone have idea about this?

The Browser participate in the CA/Browsers Forum. The other party is the Public CAs. Some call them "the cartel". Browsers have a security model called the "browser security model" or the "web app security model". In this security model, a collection of predefined trusted anchor point are used.

The cartel expects end-entity (server) certificates to be signed by a public CA in the trusted store that the browsers carry around with them. There's some hand waiving with "carry around" because Chromium uses the Operating System's trust store.

I expect you probably did not install the self-signed certificate properly for the other browsers you are testing.

You did not show us the certificate that's causing you trouble, so we can only speculate if its well formed or valid. But I'll try to answer your question on Key Usage and Extended Key Usage.

---

> My openssl.conf file was structured like this...

```
[ mysection ]
keyUsage         = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning
```

This is an odd combination. Are you using it? If so, why are you using it? (It would be helpful if you posted your certificate).

Below are some greps of certificates from Google, Microsoft and Yahoo. Their server certificates *do not* include code signing, and they include some additional usage.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -A 1 -i key
...
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
--
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                30:11:ED:AE:FE:C3:60:32:1D:CF:9C:B7:4B:B4:E3:DD:2D:1D:FC:40
--
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:4A:DD:06:16:1B:BC:F6:68:B5:76:F5:81:B6:BB:62:1A:BA:5A:81:2F

$ openssl s_client -connect www.microsoft.com:443 | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -A 1 -i key
...
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
--
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                2B:DB:4A:3F:90:02:48:9E:0F:89:21:E2:EB:4A:73:1E:E0:0F:85:6B
--
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:EB:DB:11:5E:F8:09:9E:D8:D6:62:9C:FD:62:9D:E3:84:4A:28:E1:27

$ openssl s_client -connect www.yahoo.com:443 | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -A 1 -i key
...
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
--
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:0D:44:5C:16:53:44:C1:82:7E:1D:20:AB:25:F4:01:63:D8:BE:79:A5
```

---

> Certificate with Extended Key Usage only works in Firefox...

According to [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), Extended Key Usage is optional. The other standard is the [CA/Browser Forums Baseline Requirements](http://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/), and its the policy used by most Public CAs to issue certificates. I can't tell what the CA/B BR says about it with respect to end entity certs because it so confusing.

***Key Usage***

First, the Key Usage for RSA certificates is usually `digitalSignature` and `keyEncipherment`.

If you have a certificate with Diffie-Hellman parameters, then you would use `keyAgreement`. I've never seen signatures with Diffie-Hellman (I think that's ElGamal signing), so I don't believe a cert with Diffie-Hellman parameters should include `digitalSignature`.

You should not use `dataEncipherment` because you don't want to do bulk encryption with the key; rather you *only* want to transport a key that's used for bulk encryption (vis-à-vis `keyEncipherment`).

And `nonRepudiation` means nothing, so don't use it.

***Extended Key Usage***

Second, the RFCs state (in Section 4.2.1.12): *"[EKU] indicates one or more purposes for which the certified public key may be used, in addition to or in place of the basic purposes indicated in the key usage extension"*. Under the [CA/Browser Forums Baseline Requirements](http://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/), I ***think*** Extended Key Usage is optional for end entity certificates. I can only say "I think" because Appendix (B)(3)(G) is confusing. I'm fairly certain EKU is mandatory for Subordinate CA certificates, though.

Because I treat Extended Key Usage an optional attribute, I usually omit it. If I were going to include it, I would use `serverAuth` and possibly `clientAuth` (they should be mutually exclusive, but I often see them both in a certificate).

***Configuration File***

Here's the CONF file I use for generating self-signed certificates for testing. Its minimal, and does not include the extra sections from OpenSSL's configuration file. I've never had a problem with it in libraries or browsers.

You will have to uncomment `# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth` and modify it to suit your taste.

```
# Self Signed (note the addition of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
# Signing Request (note the lack of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.req.pem
# Print it:
#     openssl x509 -in example-com.cert.pem -text -noout
#     openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout

[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

# The Subject DN can be formed using X501 or RFC 4514 (see RFC 4519 for a description).
#   Its sort of a mashup. For example, RFC 4514 does not provide emailAddress.
[ subject ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = NY

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = New York

organizationName         = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example, LLC

# Use a friendly name here because its presented to the user. The server's DNS
#   names are placed in Subject Alternate Names. Plus, DNS names here is deprecated
#   by both IETF and CA/Browser Forums.
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Example Company

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

# Section x509_ext is used when generating a self-signed certificate. I.e., openssl req -x509 ...
[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

# Section req_ext is used when generating a certificate signing request. I.e., openssl req ...
[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = example.com
DNS.2       = www.example.com
DNS.3       = mail.example.com
DNS.4       = ftp.example.com

# Add these if you need them. But usually you don't want them or
#   need them in production. You may need them for development.
# DNS.5       = localhost
# DNS.6       = localhost.localdomain
# DNS.7       = 127.0.0.1

# IPv6 localhost
# DNS.8     = ::1
# DNS.9     = fe80::1
```

Comment: amazing answer imo