# Installing SSL Certificates

Tags: express, ssl, sails.js, ssl-certificate

Follow up on the question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296131/obtaining-csr-file-for-ssl-in-aws-windows-instance) already.

I have Amazon AWS Instance running Windows 2013 server. I have used IIS 8 to generate CSR file. I have used that CSR file in godaddy.com for SSL certificates.

Go daddy gave me following files:
 - somerandomhash.crt (2KB)
 - gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt (5KB)

In my Sails.js (express.js) I have:

```
serverOptions : {
    key: fs.readFileSync(my.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(my.cert)        
}
```

I have used http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ to create test certificate for my testing domain. That web site provided me with two files, key and cert that work just fine with (ip domain).
Now I need to used proper SSL and I have problems.

How do I update my configuration (serverOptions) to use files provided by godaddy? I do not see a key file anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not godaddy customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of reading this is final solution:

I was getting the following error:

> routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line node.js

No matter what I do I always get that error. Other people who got same error, suggested to add extra enter on header and footer of the request. In my case it did not help. What helped me is Notepad++ and EoL conversion.

I guess you can do it with other editors, but I used Notepad++. Just edit-->EoL Conversion and make sure Windows is selected.

Hopefully it will save time for other people who experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

IIS should've generated a key along with the CSR. http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905 Your SSL provider will not make a key for you, that'd be terribly insecure - you're the only one who's supposed to have a private key.

`gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` is a certificate chain file, and should be added to `serverOptions` like so:

```
serverOptions : {
    key: fs.readFileSync(my.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(my.cert),        
    ca: fs.readFileSync(my.ca)        
}
```

Comment: IIS did not offer me key. It only generated the CSR... I have already used it against SSL Provider. If I need to create SSL from scratch, so be it, but I am afraid I will not get my key again

Comment: @Wexoni I linked to how you get your key out of IIS.

Comment: I have followed the procedure you linked, and I got the command issued with success... now where did the key go? I guess there is a place with the keys on the drive..

Comment: I just cant find the key file. It seems that IIS hides the key from me... but I need the key for node.js

Comment: A quick Googling for "IIS export private key" brings up http://serverfault.com/questions/302147/exporting-ssl-cert-private-keys-in-iis-7-0.

Comment: Thank you for the thread. I tried it, and I ended up with 6KB file with extension *.pfx. I used the last suggestion using export option...